# Geometric Distributions of Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, ...$ are random variables that are independent and geometric, although perhaps with different parameters. Find as many of the following as is feasible: $X_1+X_2, X_1+X_2+X_3$, and so on.

Attempt at Solution:
$P_1(X_1=n) = (1-P_1)^{n-1}*P_1 \\
P_2(X_2=n) = (1-P_2)^{n-1}*P_2 \\
P(X_1+X_2=n) = (P_1(X_1=0) + P_2(X_2=n)) + (P_1(X_1=1)+P_2(X_2=n-1))+... = \sum_{j=o}^n{P_1(X_1=j)+P_2(X_2=n-j)} \\
P(X_1+X_2+X_3=n)=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^j[P_1(X_1=j-i)+P_2(X_2=i)+P_3(X_3=n-j)] \\
P(X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4=n)=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^k\sum_{i=0}^j [P_1(X_1=k-j)+P_2(X_2=j-i)+P_3(X_3=i)+P_4(X_4=n-k)] \\
P(X_1+X_2+X_3+...+X_m=n)=\sum_{a_1=0}^n\sum_{a_2=0}^{a_1}...\sum_{a_{m-1}=0}^{a_{m-2}} [P_1(X_1=a_{m-1})+P_2(X_2=a_{m-2}-a_{m-1})+...+P_{m-1}(X_{m-1}=a_2-a_1)+P_m(X_m=n-a_1)]$

Does this make sense? Would this give the probabilities?

Comment: You'll want to look at how you're breaking up the independent random variables into two separate probabilities. You've added them, when you should be multiplying.

Comment: Wait, so it should be $\sum_{j=0}^n [P_1(X_1=j)*P_2(X_2=n-j)]$? And each of the probabilities will be multiplied through for each j-value and then those will be summed? Does everything else loo good?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The rest after that will have to change, but it's trivial.